# $T$ is an $L^2$-bounded operator; find its norm

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

We have the integral operator
$$
P:L^2(\Bbb R^n)\to\{\text{meas.functions}\;:\;\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R\}
$$
defined as
$$
Tf(x):=\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dy
$$
where $L$ is a measurable function on $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ such that
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n}|L(x,y)|\,dx\le\beta\;\;\;\forall y\in\Bbb R^n\\
\int_{\Bbb R^n}|L(x,y)|\,dy\le\beta\;\;\;\forall x\in\Bbb R^n\;\;.
$$
We know $T$ is bounded on $L^2$; what we have to prove is that the $L^2$ operator norm of $T$ is $\le C\beta$ for some constant $C>0$ (but maybe $C=1$).

I took $f\in L^2$ and I tried (using various Calculus theorems)
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\|_2^2
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|Tf(x)\right|^2\,dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dy\right|^2\,dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dy\right)
\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,z)f(z)\,dz\right)\,dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)L(x,z)\,dx\right)\,dx\,f(y)f(z)\,dydz\\
\end{align*}

but this didn't helped me.

I noticed that if
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dy\right|^2\,dx=
\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dx\right|^2\,dy\\
$$

I could conclude, but I don't know how to prove this.

I tried even to use the identity
$$
\|Tf\|_p^p=p\int_0^{+\infty}r^{p-1}\lambda_{Tf}(r)\,dr
$$
where
$$
\lambda_{Tf}(r):=|\{x:|Tf(x)|>r\}|
$$
but without success.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
\begin{align*}
\|Tf\|_2^2
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|Tf(x)\right|^2\,dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\int_{\Bbb R^n}L(x,y)f(y)\,dy\right|^2\,dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left|\langle\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|},f(\cdot)\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|}\rangle\right|^2 dx\\
&\le
\int_{\Bbb R^n}
\left|\langle\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|},\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|}\rangle\right|\left|
\langle f(\cdot)\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|},f(\cdot)\sqrt{|L(x,\cdot)|}\rangle\right| dx\\
&=\int_{\Bbb R^n}\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}|L(x,y)|\,dy\right)\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n}|L(x,y)||(f(y))|^2\,dy\right)\,dx
\end{align*}
from which we can easily conclude.

The inequality follows from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.